# How to select multiple items in a subquery SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, subquery, output, query-optimization

I have a query which select multiple items using a subquery as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A2P.aid, P.pid 
FROM sub_aminer_author2paper A2P, sub_aminer_paper P
WHERE DATALENGTH(P.p_abstract_SWR) > 0
AND P.pid IN (SELECT pid 
              FROM sub_aminer_author2paper
              WHERE p_year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2014 
              AND aid = 677
             )
AND A2P.aid = 677
ORDER BY A2P.aid
```

It gives the output as:

```
aid pid  
677 812229  
677 812486  
677 818273  
677 975105  
677 1129619  
677 1626166  
677 1924898  
677 2014164  
677 2070844
```

I want to have same output if I use multiple values for `aid` as `aid IN (SELECT aid FROM Authors)` and `A2P.aid IN (SELECT aid FROM Authors)`. But if I use to execute this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A2P.aid, P.pid 
FROM sub_aminer_author2paper A2P, sub_aminer_paper P
WHERE DATALENGTH(P.p_abstract_SWR) > 0
AND P.pid IN (SELECT pid 
              FROM sub_aminer_author2paper
              WHERE p_year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2014 
              AND aid IN (677, 1359)
             )
AND A2P.aid IN (677, 1359)
ORDER BY A2P.aid
```

It multiplies the output for each number of `aid`'s as output for two `aid`'s (for example) should be `125` rows but it gives `250` rows (125 * 2) i.e. `125` rows for `aid` i.e. `677` and `125` rows for `aid` i.e. `1359`. Similarly, output for three `aid`'s (for example) should be `191` rows but it gives `573` rows (191 * 3) i.e. `191` rows for each `aid`.

How can I modify this query?

Comment: whats the purpose of that subquery? why don't you join the 2 tables?

Comment: @Aツ I have to specify time i.e. `p_year` and also `aid` that's why using subquery

Comment: but if you select `FROM sub_aminer_author2paper A2P JOIN sub_aminer_paper P ON P.pid=A2P.pid
WHERE DATALENGTH(P.p_abstract_SWR) > 0
AND p.p_year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2014 
AND aid IN (677, 1359)` if this does not work, why?

Comment: @Aツ Thanks, well it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using A's comments the query can be modified as:

```
SELECT A2P.aid, P.pid
FROM sub_aminer_author2paper A2P 
JOIN sub_aminer_paper P ON P.pid = A2P.pid 
WHERE DATALENGTH(P.p_abstract_SWR) > 0 
AND P.p_year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2014 
AND A2P.aid IN (SELECT aid FROM Authors)
ORDER BY A2P.aid
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you reference a column from the outer query in the sub-query and thus the sub-query is actually useless because it's always true. Make sure you always alias the table and column usage in sub-queries so you know which columns you are actually referencing.

Your actual problem here though is that you are creating a cartesian product - you don't actually have a join between sub_aminer_author2paper and sub_aminer_paper - add a join clause (in the WHERE or using ANSI-92 using INNER/OUTER JOIN).